# Android Studio, adding multiple images on click

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener

JAVA:

```
package com.example.scott.testapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class HomeScreen extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout Backround;
    Button InitButton;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    Backround = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Backround);
    InitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.InitButton);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);


        InitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                /*insert code here*/    

            }
        });


    }



}
```

In order to insert the image, i'm thinking that I need to use a command like ImageView image = new (image), and then use another command to draw it on the display. I dont know which commands I should use.
XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Backround"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/DESERT2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Initiate"
        android:id="@+id/InitButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to create the image on the event of the click of a button, I also created the ImageView in the xml file. Not sure if I should change something there.

Comment: Where you want to add images to layout or in imageView?

Comment: in layout. I want to add them to the main display

Comment: could you please show to image what you planing to do ? Why you not using GridView or ListView?

Answer (score -1):

you can use

> image.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourDesiredImageName);

Comment: how does this adding multiple images on the ImageView instance?